# post installation code in ClickOnce

Tags: installation, clickonce

Is there any way to place code (`C#`) that will be executed after `ClickOnce` installation, without running the application?
I saw Microsoft's 'custom installer', which is a nice way to say "why don't you create an installer application", which I prefer not to (I want my users to have a single - well, double - click and that's that).
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce applications run when installed - so you could essentially just bootstrap your own application.

You could either put some code at the start of the main entry point. Or, my preferred approach, you could create a second wrapper application. You would make the wrapper be the app installed by clickonce and install the real exe along side it. In the wrapper write your custom code and then when you're done launch and real exe using the Process class.